# Send email for total items in a SharePoint 2013 list

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

How do I create an automated email in SP2013 that will give the total number of items in a SP2013 list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is possible using workflows as in my opinion there is no way to check the total item count in your list. Workflows are triggered on item adding and imo you can only have properties of the current item. 
Unless you work with a newly created list and use the itemID. This would always increment the ID with the count of total items but whenever you delete an item, your count is wrong so don't use that.

I would create a farm solution that handles the onitemadded event of your list. You can then easily get the list object out of the SPItemEventProperties coming with the event receiver. 
Then do something like this (sorry i don't have my dev environment here for the moment):

```
SPQuery query = SPQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
List mylist = properties.List;

SPListItemCollection items = mylist.getItems(query);

int totalCount = items.Count;

if(totalCount < 16){
//SEND EMAIL LOGIC
}
```

Sending email can just be done through C#.

**Bonus:** if you want to reuse this logic, you can always create a custom action/condition for SharePoint workflows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately I do not have farm access to my company SharePoint. I will just create an alert for whenever an item is removed from the list. I will also add the count of list items using totals in edit view menu. This way when the alert is emailed, whoever receives the email can just click on the link to the list and see the count total. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger sending email through using task scheduler(on certain intervals) on your server (or any other server if you use the clientside OM). Other option is using an event receiver: in the itemadded event, count the total items and send email through c#. 
Your question is rather short, so adding some more detail, it would be easier to give you a complete answer

Comment: I have a basic SP list of 20 items, as items are deleted off of the list, I'll need an automated email to be sent to me when 15 items are left. Hope this helps a little bit. If I need to create a workflow, do you know of any step by step tutorials that can show me how?

Answer (score 0):

Cool code, but there's an easy, and more complete out of the box way to accomplish this.

To get the total items:

Create a single line text field in List A called ListA_ID. Create one line item and set this field to a value of your choosing.

Add a lookup column to ListB called ListA_ID_lookup (All items created on this list need to be set to the same value created in List A).

Create a new lookup column in ListA called "Total Number of Values in List B"

Set the lookup to get information from: List B
In this column: ListA_ID_lookup (Count Related)

The count related field on List A will report the total number of items that matches the look up column.

Then you can create a looping workflow in some fashion that sends an updates email on an interval of your choosing. When list items from B are updated, I would create a workflow to update a field in List A, which would initiate a workflow to email from List A. If "Total Number of Values in List B" less than 20, Email action, etc. etc.

There are a few ways to do this email part.